# GitLab CI/CD - Change Working Directory

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, terraform

I am trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline for Terraform, however I need to change the pwd before running any further commands.

It appears the Terraform container only accepts Terraform commands, so cd/ls/echo $PATH are unrecognised. Do I need build an image which supports this and use that, or can I use the maintained Terraform images?

I tried changing the ENTRYPOINT but appears only a minimal install is available due to the Alpine image.

Comment: Please show us some code (ideally a [minimal, complete and verifiable example of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and what it actually does. Otherwise this is just not debuggable.

Answer (score 23):

You can change the entrypoint to `/usr/bin/env` in order to run a cd command. Example with gitlab-ci:

```yaml
validate_terraform:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/env"]
  stage: test

  script:
    - cd infrastructure/
    - terraform init
    - terraform validate
```

Comment: The correct syntax for the entrypoint would be: 
`entrypoint: - "/usr/bin/env"`, since it expects an array of strings

Comment: `entrypoint` is fine. Brackets work in yaml to designate arrays

Comment: It's worth clarifying that this changes the [docker ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). This has much wider implications beyond simply "changing the working directory"

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a generic image like `alpine` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` and get the Terraform inside your script like:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_386.zip
unzip terraform*
```

and use it like:

```
./terraform [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I have had the same issue today. I found the following post which helped me to solve:
[Is there any way to have Terraform CLI runs scripts in a directory other than PWD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993858/is-there-any-way-to-have-terraform-cli-runs-scripts-in-a-directory-other-than-pw)

So I use the chdir flag in my gitlab-ci:

```
- terraform -chdir=infrastructure init
- terraform -chdir=infrastructure validate
  ...
```

Documentation: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands#switching-working-directory-with-chdir