# Is there any way to have Terraform CLI runs scripts in a directory other than PWD?

Tags: terraform

I understand that when I run terraform CLI within a directory, it takes all the terraform artifacts from the current directory.

Is it possible to have terraform apply and terraform plan to look for scripts in a directory other than current PWD such that I don't have to keep changing current directory?

Comment: How would that be different than:
`cd $NEW_DIR; terraform apply`?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, I am building shell scripts that do things more that just terraform and it needs take data from many realtive path

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, regardsless of alternate options, I like to know if the feature exists or not.

Comment: You can just pass in the directory you want to apply. https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html

Comment: @Adrian, I am not able find that in the link you shared. Can you give me the option you are refering to.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, do I need to do terraform init in that directory too?

Comment: The link works for me, but you can get the same info from terraform help apply

Comment: @Adrian, I can go to link. But which exact switch are refering to?I am not able to find any refrence in the link to your comment "You can just pass in the directory you want to apply"

Comment: No switch. It's the parameter to the command. It's explained in the description.

Answer (score 6):

At the time I'm writing this, Terraform v0.14.0 is currently in release candidate and its final release is expected in the next few weeks.

That new version will introduce a new feature to allow requesting that Terraform switch directory itself before running any of its subcommands. For example:

```
terraform -chdir=subdirectory init
terraform -chdir=subdirectory apply
```

This is essentially the same as launching Terraform with the current working directory already set to the given subdirectory, but with two minor differences:

- Terraform will set the `path.cwd` value to be the directory where Terraform was run from, rather than the subdirectory. As before, `path.root` is the directory containing the root module, so both directories are available.
- If your [CLI configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/cli-config.html) includes paths that Terraform resolves during its startup then they will be resolved relative to the original working directory, because the directory switch applies only to the behavior of the given subcommand, not to actions Terraform takes prior to running the subcommand.

Neither of these differences are usually significant for common Terraform use, so in most cases you can think of the `-chdir=` option as having the same effect as switching into the target directlry using `cd` first.

Comment: Is there a configuration based approach to setting this value (like a `.terraform.cfg`) so that you can set it once and forget it?